# Recursion calls in Merge sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

Running merge sort and printing the left part gives me the following output for given input, I am not able to understand why it is printing `2` at the end. Please help me with how this recursive calls are

Input: (size of array and in the next line is the array)

```
5 
8 5 4 2 1
```

and the output is

```
8
5 8
4 5 8
2
1 2 4 5 8
```

here is my full code for reference, it is very standard algorithm so just check `mergesort` function and see what I am trying to print.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector<int> merge(vector<int>&B, vector<int>&C) {
    int n = B.size() + C.size();
    vector<int> D(n);
    for (int t{}; t < n; t++)
        D[t] = 0;
    int i{}, j{}, k{};
    
    while (i < B.size() && j < C.size()) {
        if (B[i] < C[j]) {
            D[k] = B[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        } else {
            D[k] = C[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    if (i < B.size()) {
        while (i < B.size()) {
            D[k] = B[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        while (j < C.size()) {
            D[k] = C[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return D;
}

vector<int> merge_sort(vector<int> &A, int left, int right) {
    vector <int> B, C, A_;
    if (left == right) {
        A_.push_back(A[left]);  
        return A_;
    }
    int m = (left + right) / 2; //possible error, convert this to int then
    B = merge_sort(A, left, m);

    for (int i{}; i < B.size(); i++)
        cout << B[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    C = merge_sort(A, m + 1, right);
    A_ = merge(B, C);
    return A_;
}

int main() {
    int n; 
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> vec(n);
    for (int i{}; i < n; i++)
        cin >> vec[i];
    vector<int> sorted_vec = merge_sort(vec, 0, vec.size() - 1);
    
    for (int i{}; i < n; i++)
        cout << sorted_vec[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why write `int i{}` instead of the more explicit and readable `int i = 0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you call cout only on the left side of the vector (for each recursion call) in a depth first visit: you always print what happens on the left and only for the left nodes (and after the left side has been sorted). This drawing should help you understanding:

[image]

- 85421 represents your first call to merge_sort.
  There you have vector B (854) and vector C (21)

  - you then call merge_sort on 854. Here you have vector B (85) And vector C (4)

    - you then call merge_sort on 85. Here you have vector B (8) and vector C (5)

      - The vector with one element is sorted.
    - you print the B vector (8)
    - you call merge_sort on (5)

      - The vector with one element is sorted.
    - you merge (8) and (5) to have (58)
    - you return (58) as B to the calling method
  - you print B vector (58)
  - you call merge_sort on (4)

    - (4) is already sorted
  - you merge (58) and (4) to (458) and return (458) as B to the calling method
- you print B vector (458)
- you call merge sort on (21) vector B is (2) and vector C is (1)

  - call merge sort on (2) and you get back (2) as B on the caller method
  - you print (2)
  - you call merge_sort on (1)
  - you merge (2) and (1) as (12) and send (12) back as C to the caller method
- you merge (458) and (12) and (12458) is the result.
- you print (12458) in the main

Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: nicely explained, by the way do you feel understanding this helps in competitive programming or coding interviews?

Comment: Well, I think that a good programmer should know what the programs that she/he code are going to do :)